# Python WordCloud API colours

Tags: python, nlp, word-cloud

What does the colours in a WordCloud represent? I am using the python API for WordCloud which assigns random colours (atleast according to me) to words. Am I missing something and do these colours actually mean anything?

Tried creating a lot of wordclouds and could not grasp at the concept of colours in the wordcloud

Comment: According to the [doc](https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html#wordcloud.WordCloud) it is random. You can specify a function with kwarg `color_func`.